# Programmatically created uiview doesn't response at first click

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

Mostly, I've got elements created on AutoLayout, but there are some uiviews which are created programmatically. There is an event which have to change some logic and UI. Everything is working fine, except programmatically created uiviews. They change their state only after second click. Furthermore, if I click on another programmatically created uiview, the previous uiviews lose their current state and back to default. Probably, there could be a problem with threads, I tried some combinations of `dispatch_async`, but it didn't help.

Here is the event:

```
func actFilterComfort(sender: UIButton) {
    let subview = self.labelSettingViewComfort.subviews[0] as UIView
    let imageView = sender.superview?.viewWithTag(120) as! UIImageView

    if(!filters.comfort) {
        filters.comfort = true
        filters.comfortImage.frame = CGRectMake(self.comfortDisplay.frame.origin.x + (CGFloat(filters.counter) * 10.0), 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)
        self.comfortDisplay.hidden = true
        subview.addSubview(filters.comfortImage)
        subview.sendSubviewToBack(filters.comfortImage)

        imageView.alpha = 1

        filters.counter += 1
    }
    else {
        filters.comfort = false

        imageView.alpha = 0

        filters.comfortImage.removeFromSuperview()
        if(filters.counter == 1) {
            self.comfortDisplay.hidden = false
        }
        else {
            self.alignFiltersImages(subview, counter: filters.counter)
        }
        filters.counter -= 1
    }
}
```

`imageView` is a programmatically created uiview. It should change its alpha, but it doesn't. Other things work well.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to change image alpha.
Create an extension for UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {
    func setImageAlpha(alpha:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        let area = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height);

        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, .Multiply);
        CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, alpha);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, self.CGImage);

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
}
```

Use below code for changing image alpha in imageView after setting imageView alpha:

```
imageView.image = imageView.image?.setImageAlpha(1.0)
```

You can also set hidden property for imageview show and hide instead of setting alpha. When alpha is 0 at that time set imageView.hidden = true and when alpha is 1  at that time set imageView.hidden = false

Comment: No, it doesn't work at first time. I think, the problem is connected to the definition of this uiview. Because it doesn't work only on the first click. Then it starts working well. It seems like uiview are defined on the first click, and it's stored somewhere in the thread, and only after that start changing its properties.

Comment: change initial value of filters.comfort if it's true than change it with false and if it's false than change it with true